# Bug with reading file

Tags: c++, linux

I am working on data transfer and calculating crc. What i observe on my computer is that this code that outputs binary data of blob file from address 0x2420 to 0x2430 outputs

```
4f ef ff c0 48 ef 0 f8 0 48 ef 7c 0 0 28 30
```

where it should

```
4f ef ff c0 48 ef 0 f8 0 c0 48 ef 7c 0 0 28
```

that is seen using xxd or hexdump (hexdump has wrong endianes)

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>

template<typename iterator>
uint32_t PrintData(iterator it,int len)
{    
   for(int i = 0; i < len;  i++ )
   {
      std::cout<<std::hex<<(uint32_t)*it<<" ";
      it++;
   }
   std::cout <<std::endl;
   return 0;
}


int main()
{
    std::ifstream file;
    file.open("blob",std::fstream::in | std::fstream::binary);
    std::istream_iterator<uint8_t> stream(file.seekg(0x2420,std::ios::beg));        
    PrintData(stream,16);
}
```

source and data
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B4BEBIblI7RPTnFjYU8zU0cyQlk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Try with `istreambuf_iterator`.

Comment: @ jrok , that was it. Issue was that c0 is some whitespace that is filtered out.